# MapKit Memory Leaks (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios10

create new project just with MapKitView and i get many memory leaks in iOS 10, but on iOS 9 all ok.
20 minutes use map in iOS 10 and app crashed by memory warning.

[image: iOS 10 have leaks. iOS 9 - OK]

[image]

UPD: This trouble only in iOS 10.1, 10.0 - OK, 10.2 (Beta) - OK

Comment: You can add some example code of what you did just in case

Comment: I specially create empty project with one ViewController and i add MKMapView through Storyboard to View